# Why would upgrading your laptop to Windows 10 affect game performance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

Since I've upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10, my Minecraft becomes more laggy. So, I wonder if that was the cause of the lack of FPS in my Minecraft?

Comment: It's likely related yes. When you 'upgraded' did you also upgrade all of the drivers for things like the graphics chip/card?

Comment: Of course I did

Comment: What's the rest of your system specs? Is the laptop older? I know when I upgraded my laptop from Windows 8 to 10 it ran significantly slower, so I reverted back.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M 4GB RAM

Comment: @TimmyJim ^^^^^^

Comment: @Raptr yea those specs are quite low for Windows 10.  Your definitely low on resources for games.  It's almost unheard of for laptops to have 4gb or RAM now a days.

Comment: @TimmyJim any suggestions ?

Comment: Most laptops aren't capable of many upgrades - at least not to the motherboard or CPU.  You may be able to put more RAM in it, depending on if the RAM is soldered onto the board directly or if it uses [SO-DIMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM).  If it's SO-DIMM, you can swap in better RAM, but make sure its compatible with the laptop.  The [CPU you have](https://ark.intel.com/products/52224/Intel-Core-i5-2410M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz) is over six years old.  I would say the best thing you can do is go back to Windows 7.  Windows 10 is a bit more resource hungry than 7.

Comment: Although you are within the Minimum specs for Windows 10, I had a similar issue on my laptop that has newer hardware (still 4Gb of RAM though) when I went from Windows 8 to 10.  So I downgraded it back to 8 and everything was better.

Comment: @Timmy Jim oh , now i clearly understand whats happening. Thanks for that help. Really appreciate that :D

Answer (score 2):

There would be a number of factors that would cause this following an upgrade.

1. Drivers - By default, windows 10 will use it's own reference drivers, over the optimized, more effective drivers produced by the hardware manufacturer. Make sure all your drivers are up to date AND Windows 10 compatible.
2. Settings - It's possible the upgrade has removed settings from your hardware, which results in performance losses. Check your settings are correct for your drivers and software.
3. Disk Space - Windows 10 Upgrade uses a fair amount of space for upgrade. You could possibly be running low, causing poor general performance (loading chunks from the disk etc). Perform a disk cleanup and (if you DON'T have an SSD), perform a full disk de-fragmentation
4. Running Programs - Some programs installed on your PC previously may not be fully windows 10 compatible. They could possibly not run as efficiently as ones which are. Ensure your programs are designed to run with Windows 10. Also, check that you are only running programs that you require. Unused programs will affect performance.
5. Background tasks - Windows 10 adds a lot of backround processes which could be affecting performance. Use Services.msc to find out whats running, and check web sources to discover if you need it running. Do this with care, as you can break your PC by turning off needed services. A number of these services are known data-miners, so you might be sending lots of data to microsoft that you really don't need to.

I've tried to present this list in the order in which I think is most likey causes for a slowdown following a windows 10 upgrade.

We could provide more specific answers, if we had an idea of your system specifications, and an overview of how your system is configured currently.

Answer (score 1):

It *shouldn't*. I'm not an expert with computers, but when I upgraded to Win10 I didn't see a noticeable drop in performance. Make sure that your settings in Minecraft are where they were.

From what I've heard, the Window's 10 edition of Minecraft (as in, the edition made for Windows 10. Not the normal launcher that you get from minecraft.net) is laggy. I haven't bought it though.

Comment: The windows 10 version of Minecraft is not the same as the Java version. Windows 10, is more like the version available on the Xbox One and mobile devices.

Comment: I know that. Win10 is referring to Window 10. The actual OS version of Windows. I referred to Window's 10 edition of Window's 10 edition.